# Наверху, но внизу

Tags: семантика

Вроде бы парные формы, антонимы. Но при этом разные приставки (они же - древние предлоги). "Вверху" еще можно сказать, но не так распространено - и с некоторым оттенком значения. "Нанизу" - не слышал.

Можно чем-то объяснить такой разный "выбор" приставок?

Comment: Нас учитель учил, если между предлогом и словом можно вставить слово, то пишется раздельно, например: в самом низу - в низу, на самом верху - на верху.?

Answer (score 3):

У Ушакова есть  *нанизу*, но уже с пометой *прост.*:

НАНИЗУ́, нареч. (прост.). Внизу. «Он, бедный, нанизу облизывал лишь губы.» Крылов.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Я думаю, что одно из значений *приставки на*- — "находиться сверху" (ср. *настольный*). А если учитывать значение корня  *низ*, то приставка *на*- здесь как бы неуместна. Приставка *в-* более органична. Поэтому ушёл постепенно вариант *нанизу*.

Можно, наверное, использовать *предлог* *на* в сочетаниях типа *на низу сундука*, но и так выражаются всё реже.

Comment: Насчет "на" согласен. На - это сверху по семантике. А вот "в" с этих позиций объясняется плохо. Вот если  брать аналогию с горой, холмом, и предлагать, что "на" - это на вершине, то внизу это - **у** подножия. **унизу** было бы интересным "решением". Или у Вас есть какая-то другая "модель", помимо холма?

Comment: У приставки в- одно из значений — движение внутрь, нахождение внутри. Внизу - это взгляд сверху в некое пространство, в котором находится объект. С того же холма смотрите вниз и видите там нечто. А вот "вверху" с этих позиций объяснить труднее (хотя тоже возможно); может, поэтому предпочитаем "наверху" и "сверху"?

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, так моделировалось пространство, состоящее из ВЕРХНЕЙ плоскости и остальной объемной части, которую называли НИЗОМ.

Предмет мог находиться наверху ("на крыше") или внизу (в объеме).

Comment: *Vera, что-то мой комментарий пропал, надеюсь, это глюк, а не модератор. Я повторю.* Можно Ваше понимание представить в виде водного объекта - **на** поверхности, но **в** глубине?  Я правильно понял?

Comment: Ну да,  это единая модель для любого пространства: водного, воздушного.

Comment: У воздушного нет "поверхности". Ладно, мысль я понял.

Answer (score 0):

Употребление «нанизу» встретить можно:

> Река искрилась огненной чешуёй от встающего солнца. Лёгкий ветерок
> играл среди островов, и сменяли один другой пряные запахи: илом,
> опавшей листвой, камышами и беспредельной степью, которая сменила
> здесь Олешье. И снова, княжая ладья впереди, караван вытянулся по
> старому Днепру к домам отчим… И по знаку Свентельда все осмотрели
> оружие и положили его так, чтобы было оно под рукой: был уже близок
> Кичкас, старый перевоз, самое узкое место Днепра **нанизу**. Здесь был
> он шириной не больше версты, течение его поэтому было очень быстро, а
> по левому берегу высились отвесные скалы. Здесь часто печенеги
> нападали на караваны и грабили их, а иногда брали только с них дань:
> вокруг расстилались их степи. Но теперь на Кичкасе никого не было ―
> только два печенега верхами стояли на скалах среди золотистых туманов…
> [И. Ф. Наживин. Глаголют стяги (1935)]. Цитата из [НКРЯ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&sr=1&docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94eC0xL25hemhpdmluL25hemhpdjAyLnhtbCMwMDE5&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&kwsz=5&mode=main&sid=464&spd=10&expand=full&out=normal).
>
> А там теметь! Нешто тут можно что увидать? Десяток-другой сажен, поди,
> будет? А **нанизу** небось вода? Казаки зашумели; на арестанта посыпались
> со всех сторон угрозы, брань. ― Вот что я скажу вам, господа служивые,
> ― начал Бусов прежним ровным голосом (он только страшно был бледен,
> спокойствие же нашло на него удивительное с той самой минуты, как
> подошел конвой), ― не серчайте лучше, а выслухайте. Я-то с утра еще
> знаю, что, Авдотьи в живых нет на свете; а теперь и вы приметы можете
> видеть, где искать упокойницу. [П. Ф. Якубович. В мире отверженных.
> Том 2 // «Русское богатство», 1898] Цитата из [НКРЯ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&sr=1&docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94aXgveWFrdWJvdmljaF9wL3BfeWFrdTA3LnhtbCMwMzYz&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&kwsz=5&mode=main&sid=8715&spd=10&expand=full&out=normal).
>
> «Стой; здесь лежит что-то, свети сюда!» Тут пристало к ним еще
> несколько человек. «Что лежит, Влас?» «Так, как будто бы два человека:
> один наверху, другой **наниз**у; который из них чорт, уже и не
> распознаю!» «А кто наверху?» «Баба!» «Ну, вот, это ж-то и есть чорт!»
> [Н. В. Гоголь. Сорочинская ярмарка (1831-1832)] Цитата из [НКРЯ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&sr=1&docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94aXgvZ29nb2wvc29yb2NoLnhtbCMwMDE3&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&kwsz=5&mode=main&sid=419&spd=10&expand=full&out=normal).

И хотя Ушаков в своём словаре пришит, что это просторечие,

> НАНИЗУ', нареч. (простореч.). Внизу. Он, бедный, нанизу облизывал лишь
> губы. Крлв.

а Ломоносов, что это неправильное сочетание предлога «на» с именем,

> Сии предлоги раздельные весьма легко распознать можно склонением от
> слитных, ибо слитные склоняются во всех падежах: передмѣстіе,
> передмѣстія, передмѣстію, передмѣстій, передмѣстіямъ, передмѣстіями,
> передмѣстіяхъ. А раздельные предлоги правят токмо известные падежи:
> передъ мѣсто, передъ мѣстомъ, передъ мѣста, передъ мѣстами, а не
> передъ мѣста, передъ мѣсту, передъ мѣстѣ и проч. От глаголов предлоги
> никогда не отделяются: отдаю, приношу, а не отъ даю, при ношу.
> **Некоторые неправильно соединяют предлоги раздельные с именами, которые с ними знаменованием походят на наречия: ввечеру, нанизу
> вместо въ вечеру, на низу, ибо вечеръ и низъ суть существительные с
> предлогами, сочиненные в пристойных падежах и в надлежащем
> знаменовании.** Действительно претворяются имена с предлогами в
> наречия и с ними слитно поставлены быть должны, 1) когда предлог стоит
> не с пристойным падежом, например, вдругъ, ибо и никакой другой
> предлог с именительным падежом не сочиняется; 2) когда от надлежащего
> знаменования в сложении отходит, напр. , вмѣстѣ, ибо здесь разумеется
> купно; итак, писать должно: жить вмѣстѣ съ братомъ; жить въ мѣстѣ
> многолюдномъ; 3) ежели предлог стоит перед именем, в других случаях не
> употребительным: вдоль, вкось. § 130 [М. В. Ломоносов. Российская
> грамматика (1755)]  Цитата из [НКРЯ](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&sr=1&docid=bWFpbi9zb3VyY2UvcHJlMTk1MC94dmlpaS9sb21vbm9zb3YvbG9tXzAxLnhtbCMwMDIz&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83&kwsz=5&mode=main&sid=557&spd=10&expand=full&out=normal).

на мой взгляд «нанизу», имеет право на существование, потому что означает не то же самое, что «внизу».

То, что Ломоносов пишет, что *«некоторые неправильно соединяют предлоги раздельные с именами, которые с ними знаменованием походят на наречия: …нанизу…»* говорит о том, что такое использование в его времена всё-таки было.

Дело в том, что «внизу» не является антонимом «наверху». Антонимом «внизу», является «вверху».

Предлог «в-», который соединился с «-низу» и превратился в приставку, означает направление внутрь чего-то, в данном случае внутрь пространства.

Внизу означает в нижней части пространства, а вверху — в верхней.

Если мы на корабле, то вверху (в верхней части пространства) летают птицы, а внизу (в нижней части пространства) плавают рыбы.

Предлог «на-», который соединился с «-верху» и превратился в приставку, означает нахождение на поверхности чего-то.

Наверху — это на верхней части поверхности чего-то или просто на верхней части чего-то. *«Он проворно карабкался и быстро оказался наверху»*. А «нанизу» — на нижней части поверхности чего-то или просто на нижней части чего-то. *«Она стояла нанизу»*.

Но по каким-то причинам сейчас для описания направления вверх есть два наречия «вверху» и «наверху» с немного разными значениями, а для описания направления вниз только — один «внизу», а «нанизу» считается просторечием, что на мой взгляд несправедливо.

Возможно потому, что мы живём на поверхности земли и чаще описываем, верх, чем низ, для верха у нас есть два наречия, а для низа — одно.